# Spring DB entities : Constructors, equals and hashcode

Tags: spring-data-rest

I am new to spring ..in my project which uses spring boot , web and data , I see that in all the DB entity classes it has a arg and no arg constructor , overridden hashcode and equals method . Can someone explain to me why does one need a arg and a no arg constructor and those overridden methods in the DB entity classes ..